# How to edit a really large file in Windows

Tags: windows, text-editors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Text Editor for very big file - Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/34749/text-editor-for-very-big-file-windows)

NOt a programming question I know but related to a program I am writing, and probably a problem only likely to be encountered by programmers.

I have a really big text file which I need to edit - just need to delete the first line.

None of the standard windows programs can handle the 200MB+ file

What is the best way to edit it?

Comment: This question has been asked before. You can find more information here: http://superuser.com/questions/4044/what-editor-viewer-to-use-to-inspect-large-text-based-files and here: http://superuser.com/questions/34749/text-editor-for-very-big-file-windows

Answer (score 5):

Use the sed command:

```
sed 1d largefile > newfile
mv newfile largefile
```

If you don't have sed, get Cygwin or [UnxUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) for Windows.

Comment: if you are going to edit just 1 line and you know exactly where the line is, its far easier to use sed rather than opening the file in an interactive editor.

Answer (score 3):

See [Most powerful Notepad / Text Editor replacement for Windows and Why](https://superuser.com/questions/843/most-powerful-notepad-text-editor-replacement-for-windows-and-why).

Comment: Target of this link has been deleted, but here is a link to its last known content according to the Internet Archive Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20110903154042/https://superuser.com/questions/843/most-powerful-notepad-text-editor-replacement-for-windows-and-why

Answer (score 1):

Then don't use a 'standard windows program'.

I've use `vim` in Cygwin under Windows XP to edit a 400MB file.

I don't want to do it regularly, but it worked.

EDIT: Of course, installing Cygwin *just* so you can edit a file is probably too much, but you should consider *non* standard Windows programs.

I'm not sure what the limitation of Notepad++ is, and you may consider it a 'standard', but there may be a modern third-party editor which will do the job.

Comment: Don't be snarky.

Comment: I don't see why that's *snarky* (whatever that means) I'm saying don't use a *standard* Windows program, use a non-standard Windows program.

Comment: You can also install gvim under windows without cygwin.  It should work just as well.

Answer (score 1):

UltraEdit (commercial) handles large files rather well.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a ".vbs" script to do this.
(Feel free to correct me on this one - I haven't checked the code properly)

Create a file called CopyAllButLine1.vbs, and enter the following: ({firstfile} and {secondfile} are the names of your files)

```
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile ("{firstfile}", 1)
Set outfile = objFSO.OpenTextFile ("{secondfile}")
strNextLine = objFile.Readline
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strNextLine = objFile.Readline
    outfile.WriteLine(strNextLine)
Loop
objFile.Close
outfile.close
```

Then double click your .VBS file.

Answer (score 0):

There is an editor, available either in Lite version or Professional version. This is EditPad pro from JGSoft. I registered it several years ago and kept registering the upgrades as well.

http://www.jgsoft.com.

JF

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Large Text File Viewer](http://www.swiftgear.com/ltfviewer/features.html) for reading huge server logs in the past.  It doesn't require an install and is pretty simple to use.