# Which programs can edit huge XML files comfortably?

Tags: editing, xml

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Text Editor for very big file - Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/34749/text-editor-for-very-big-file-windows)
>   [What editor/viewer to use to inspect large text based files?](https://superuser.com/questions/4044/what-editor-viewer-to-use-to-inspect-large-text-based-files)

Any text editor can do XML as long as they're small, but I need to edit XMLs way over 100MB each.

These XMLs are conversions from binary formats (and round trip binary->xml->binary doesn't change a byte), so I cannot really split any parts out. I'm trying some tricks to make the file smaller while still keeping it editable, but sheer amount of data makes it very difficult.

Are there any programs that can deal with even massive XML? At least basic functionality like editing by hand, find and replace etc., but if I could also get xml diffs, and xml search and replace with xquery or something like that, that would be just wonderful.

Comment: For which operating system?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Text Editor for very big file - Windows](http://superuser.com/questions/34749/text-editor-for-very-big-file-windows) or [What editor/viewer to use to inspect large text based files?](http://superuser.com/questions/4044/what-editor-viewer-to-use-to-inspect-large-text-based-files).  Also, see similar questions on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/159521/94928) and [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/q/1602/2904)

Comment: I normally use OSX, but I can start a VM with Linux or Windows just for that.

Comment: This should not have been closed as "exact duplicates". Editing large *XML* files and editing large text files are two completely different matters. With large XML files, you might wish to take advantage of the usual collapse/expand facilities usually offered by XML editors to walk through branches. I have an XML file with which eclipse/WTP is struggling. Even Notepad++ with the usual plugins is sluggish. So there *is* a need for streamlines XML editors.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't say which operating system, but for any operating system, [gVim](http://www.vim.org/) and [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) are obvious candidates.  They are free too.

Comment: Emacs gives me "Maximum buffer size exceeded" right away. vim is really incompatible with casual use, and I'm not a hardcore vim user.

Comment: If you rename `gvim` to `evim` it will start up in an easy mode for casual users.  It makes it non-modal and sets up key bindings the way you probably expect.

Comment: I never knew that, but there is also 'Cream for Vim' (Windows), which probably lies somewhere in the middle, as it is still modal.