# Opening a 28GB Apache access log

Tags: apache-http-server, logging, windows-server-2003

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Text Editor for very big file - Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/34749/text-editor-for-very-big-file-windows)

What is the fastest way to open a 28GB apache access log file, I need to look at the most recent entries.

OS is Windows Server 2003

Comment: This is different, I'm trying to read the very end, that question reads the entire file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I need to look at the most recent entries.

Use the [`tail`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_tail.htm) command

Comment: Windows server 2003, if you please.

Comment: @Buggy4j - it's still tail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187587/looking-for-a-windows-equivalent-of-the-unix-tail-command

Comment: And next time, remember to tag better - using 'windows-server-2003' from the outset would have avoided the confusion, especially considering apache is much more common on linux