# Problem with opening a big RTF file

Tags: microsoft-word, rtf

Someone gave me an RTF file which is 500MB. I can not open it with anything. Is there any way to open this file?

Comment: What programs have you tried so far?

Comment: Also, see here: http://superuser.com/questions/34749/text-editor-for-very-big-file-windows and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159521/text-editor-to-open-big-giant-huge-large-text-files

Comment: Notepad, Wordpad, Microsoft Word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like James T said, RTF is just plain text in the end.
If nothing helps, try opening the file with [Large Text File Viewer](http://www.swiftgear.com/ltfviewer/features.html).
Even opended up a 90GB file at work.

Comment: I opened the file using Large Text File Viewer. I wanted to copy some of it's text but it says that I can only copy up to 16MB.

Comment: Well, it's called Large Text File **Viewer**. So it's not made for copying. Maybe the app streams the file in 16mb chunks, so copying more than this amount is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

I kinda doubt that it is an rtf file. Even a several thousand page document should not be more than a few megabytes. People sometimes put different file extensions on restricted file types (like .exe) so that they can send it through email or messenger. The recipient (you) would have to know to change it back.

You can try opening it in notepad (instead of wordpad or microsoft word). If it is an rtf file, it should have a line at the top that looks kinda like this:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Calibri;}}
```

Maybe the file got garbled in transmission?

Comment: +1 for "might be a different file type". Note however, that Notepad.exe is not really suitable for very large files, as it has internal limits. If you have trouble opening the file in notepad, use Wordpad, or even better a decent editor like Notepad++.

Comment: The writer told me that she imported some pictures into it and it crashed after that. She created the file in Microsoft Word so I think it is an RTF file.

Comment: I checked the file, it is an RTF file.

Comment: @AliBZ rtf is not a very good file format to use for large file sizes and photos. Large rtf files take a long time to save/open and are not compressed. Since Word crashed, maybe it did not save properly and left you with a corrupt file. Maybe the writer could save it as a .docx or .odt (open office/libre office) or export to pdf or something. The image print resolution should be scaled down to the desired size using something like gimp or photoshop before it is imported into the document. This will make the file size smaller and make it less likely to crash when you work with it.