# How to open a 18GB text file?

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Text Editor for very big file - Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/34749/text-editor-for-very-big-file-windows)

I tried to open a 18GB text file on Windows. I first tried gVim but it crashed when I loaded the file either under editable or read only mode. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out this text file viewer:

http://www.swiftgear.com/ltfviewer/features.html

It was specifically designed for text files over 1GB in size.

Comment: Doesn't support UTF-8 but this is the best I've found too.

Answer (score 1):

disable vim plugins, run it like

```
vim -u "NONE" hugefile.log
```

Got this from
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908575/how-to-edit-multi-gigabyte-text-files-vim-doesnt-work

Answer (score 1):

I used this to open up files which are more than 8GB : http://www.sweetscape.com/010editor/

use cygwin to start using the file utilities like head, tail, grep, awk, sed for analysing part of the data and running awk or sed scripts to get an overall result