# View at least parts of a huge text file on Windows

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Text Editor for very big file - Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/34749/text-editor-for-very-big-file-windows)

I have a huge text file. Text editors refuse to open it due to it's size.
How do I view it, without using a text editor?

Solutions I can think of:

- Something like Linux's `more` command - do you know of such?
- Splitting it up to parts - how? (consider I have less available space than the size of the file)

Comment: hasn't this been asked a lot? http://superuser.com/questions/34749/text-editor-for-very-big-file-windows

Comment: It's not a duplicate! The other question asks for a text editor solution whereas here I'm asking for ALL OTHER SOLUTIONS EXCEPT FOR TEXT EDITOR !!!

Comment: Your question did not specify how big the file is and your question did not specify that you did not want to use a text editor (for what reason I cannot imagine). The link that I posted as duplicate lists many text editors that may be able to open your file like "Large Text File Viewer" and gVim. It also has a solution using the command line in cygwin. This question has been thoroughly explored. Try all the recommendations in the top three answers listed in the link and re-post your question with what you have tried. Perhaps also explain why you dont want to use a text editor.

Comment: I wrote "Text editors refuse to open it" - I took the time and tried an assortment of text editors before writing it, not all I'm sure.

Comment: Also, the reason I didn't mention the size is exactly to avoid answers such as "TextPad can handle 2GB". It doesn't matter the size, be it 2GB or 8TB.

Comment: The solution for me at least was the more command suggested here below which wasn't mentioned there

Comment: Ah ok. With a bit of re-wording and more details in the title and description to differentiate it from the other large text file questions would have helped to keep this open. Sorry for the inconvenience. I'm glad one of the solutions worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

[PSPad](http://www.pspad.com/) is a freeware tool that can also handle large files where other editors fail.

However, for really huge files (15 GB MySQL dumbs) I use UltraEdit and have set some of the options [described here](http://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials_power_tips/ultraedit/large_file_handling.html). Works without problems.