# Edit a very large textfile

Tags: windows, text-editors, text-editing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a text editor for very big files?](https://superuser.com/questions/34749/is-there-a-text-editor-for-very-big-files)

I've a 3 gigabytes big log file and I have to edit just a few rows.

With Notepad++, I can't edit the file at all. Does someone have an idea how I can edit the file?

Is there an Editor, with which I can select a range of rows i want to display?

Thank you

Best Regards

Comment: So you want to alter a log file? I don't understand the purpose of altering what it would seem is probably an automatically generated log file. Doesn't that kind of defeat the purpose of having a generated log?

Comment: http://www.emeditor.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give GVIM a go. I have edited 500MB+ sized files without any issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a unix machine, bet bet is using the built in commands like Stream Edit (SED) or Vim. Any Gui Editor will

Answer (score 0):

if they are straight forward changes, you could use *sed* to edit the file from the command-line.  You can search for particular patters or move to a particular line and make the changes.

http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html