# How to edit specific part of large text file efficiently?

Tags: emacs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a text editor for very big files?](https://superuser.com/questions/34749/is-there-a-text-editor-for-very-big-files)

How to edit specific part of large text file efficiently?  The text file is has only ASCII characters and is about 500 MB.  I always know a the string around which I'd like to do editting.  I can open up the file in Emacs and search the string, and then do editting.  Any better way?

Comment: Looks a lot like http://superuser.com/questions/34749/is-there-a-text-editor-for-very-big-files .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know regular expressions and it's a simple operation (e.g. search/replace), you probably want `sed`. Plenty of documentation is available [here](http://sed.sourceforge.net/).

There's a list of options (at least for Windows) at this Stack Overflow question: [Text editor to open big (giant, huge, large) text files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159521/text-editor-to-open-big-giant-huge-large-text-files)

Comment: No.  The edits will not be pattern based replacement.  It is traditional content edits.

Comment: In the post you referred, it says "Emacs (has a low maximum buffer size limit if compiled in 32-bit mode)".  How do I know if my Emacs is 32-bit mode or not?

Comment: On Linux at least, `M-x version` shows whether your Emacs is 32- or 64-bit.