# Viewing log files in Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a text editor for very big files?](https://superuser.com/questions/34749/is-there-a-text-editor-for-very-big-files)

I need to view log files (~10-20 million lines, about 500-1000 MB) under Windows. I just need read-only access but it would be nice to have such features as reverse search/regexp search etc.

Is there a program to do so under Windows? Text editors seems to not cope with it.

Comment: I like `less` (http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/less.htm), which isn't listed in that question since less isn't an editor.

Comment: Wait - where was anything about editing the file? (*edit*) Ok - you referred to dupliacte. I've tried to use less under cygwin but it took some time to calculate line numbers.