# MySQL File viewer/editor

Tags: windows, mysql, text-editors, database, viewer

I'm dealing with some very massive SQL files and I need to be able to go in and edit them. Are their any editors that work on Windows I can use?

I need to be able to cut out what I don't need and grab the inserts I do need without the system hanging up.

Comment: You may want to check out this [q/a for editing very large files](http://superuser.com/questions/34749/is-there-a-text-editor-for-very-big-files).

Comment: You can try dbForge Studio for MySQL, it has a powerful [mysql editor](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/mysql-query-builder.html#header).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net) to work with mysql. It works with a web browser and is quick. You need to set up a Web server for this along with phpMyAdmin. [EasyPHP](http://www.easyphp.org/) is one such [WAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAMP) server with phpMyAdmin included.

Comment: [Adminer](https://www.adminer.org/) is a smaller download and easier setup (one file!)

Answer (score 1):

There is the [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.de/products/workbench/), but I have not tested it with a large amount of data, yet. It was fine with a few hundred to thousand rows of data, though.

In case you just need a powerful text-editor, you can try [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), in my experience the most performant editor out there.