# Regexp based editing of content in large CSV files

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, sed, awk

I wanted to remove certain pattern of contents based on a regex from csv file which is very large in size containing 100,000+ records, how is it possible via windows commandline? I also have sed and awk installed in my windows commandline

It hangs on opening in **any** spreadsheet processor or text editor(Including Notepad++).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a text editor for very big files?](http://superuser.com/questions/34749/is-there-a-text-editor-for-very-big-files), [What editor/viewer to use to inspect large text based files?](http://superuser.com/questions/4044/what-editor-viewer-to-use-to-inspect-large-text-based-files), [How to access/modify large file](http://superuser.com/questions/360996/how-to-access-modify-large-file)

Comment: No , I want to process , EDIT large files based on regexp

Comment: @techie007 Updated question

Comment: Many of the editors mentioned support Regex search/replace.  If you're determined to do it from the command-line, then what have you tried already?  Did you try using `findstr`? What were the results?

Comment: I tried various editors , but I dont know about findstr

Comment: What have you tried with sed/awk? Have you tried the usual recommended editors like notepad++?

Comment: @Ali - FINDSTR is a non-starter. It has crippled regex capability, it has many bugs, and it cannot replace content.

Comment: I did try notepad++ but it crashes @m4573r

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try out [Google Refine](https://code.google.com/p/google-refine/downloads/list?can=1).

It can do complex refactoring of CSV's using several methods including REGEX.

I've used it to cleanse and manipulate very large user databases in CSV form.